# get first letter of a String (sentence) given in a column and create a new column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in pandas dataframe which has items like following,

```
SubBrand
Sam William Mathew
Jonty Rodes
Chris Gayle
```

I want to create a new column (SubBrand_new) such as

```
  SubBrand_new
0 SWM
1 JR
2 CG
```

I am using this piece of code,

```
df1["SubBrand_new"] = "".join([x[0] for x in (df1["SubBrand"].str.split())])
```

but not able to get what I am looking for. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4):

We can do split with expand and sum i.e

```
df['SubBrand'].str.split(expand=True).apply(lambda x : x.str[0]).fillna('').sum(1)

0    SWM
1     JR
2     CG
dtype: object
```

Comment: ha-ha, i had exactly the same version: `df.SubBrand.str.split(expand=True).apply(lambda c: c.str[0]).fillna('').sum(1)`, but you were faster :-D

Comment: I had `df['Abbrev'] = df['Name'].str.split(expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str[0]).apply(''.join)` but I think this is nicer +1

Comment: @EdChum my first solution was that since there were `None` I went for sum

Answer (score 2):

You want to apply a function to every line and return a new column with its result. This kind of operation can be applied with the `.apply()` method, a simple `=` attribution will not do the trick. A solution in the spirit of your code would be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Marcus Livius Drussus',
                            'Lucius Cornelius Sulla',
                            'Gaius Julius Caesar']})
df['Abrev'] = df.Name.apply(lambda x: "".join([y[0] for y in (x.split())]))
```

Which yields

```
df
    Name                    Abrev
0   Marcus Levius Drussus   MLD
1   Lucius Cornelius Sulla  LCS
2   Gaius Julius Caesar     GJC
```

**EDIT:**

I compared it to the other solution, thinking that the `apply()` method with `join()` would be pretty slow. I was surprised to find that it is in fact faster. Setting:

```
N = 3000000
bank = pd.util.testing.rands_array(3,N)
vec = [bank[3*i] + ' ' + bank[3*i+1] + ' ' + bank[3*i+2]  for i in range(N/3)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': vec})
```

I find:

```
df.Name.apply(lambda x: "".join([y[0] for y in (x.split())]))
executed in 581ms

df.Name.str.split(expand=True).apply(lambda x : x.str[0]).fillna('').sum(1)
executed in 2.81s
```

Comment: If there are 2 different names for which Abrev are coming as same, how to tackle that scenario?

Comment: What do you want for output if you have names with the same initials?

Comment: In fact list comprehension was what came to my mind when I saw the question, my way is a pandas way of doing it, since we expand it is a lot lot slower